# How to disable the iOS inset bevel effect on tableview cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to
Disable the inset bevel effect comes by default with iOS 5, see http://www.tim-oliver.com/2011/10/22/the-new-uitableview-in-ios5/, the question is - can we disable it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the separator style to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```